# Is "same thing no prob" really an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

See this answer [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13925/18061). It states,

> I try to open a pdf file and it's fine

It simply means he is using same software and phone he does not face any problem. The author himself admits that the answer does not provide any solution.

Should we remove it? Is this kind of answers allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers should offer an actual solution to the OP's problem or question. Saying "works for me" does not to that, therefore such answers should be deleted or, if they seem constructive enough, converted to a comment. In either case, the answer should be flagged for moderator attention.

For more information, see these posts on the Stack Exchange Meta:

- [Are “works for me” answers valid?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118992/194308)
- [Is “works fine here” an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167832/194308)